# mysql nested equals expression

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Why does this query returns all rows in the table in mysql?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9by6GKNcQfNE2NTvLywtxR/2

-- Schema SQL

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  u char(100),
  p char(100)
);
INSERT INTO test (u,p) VALUES ('admin', 'adminp');
INSERT INTO test (u,p) VALUES ('michelle', 'michellep');
```

-- Query SQL

```
SELECT * FROM test where p=p=1
```

Comment: What is the goal of `=1` fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When evaluating `p=p=1`, the expression first evaluates `p=p` which is trivially true (edit: at least for any non-NULL value of `p`). That is, the column `p` is always equal to itself on a given row.

In MySQL (unlike standard SQL), a boolean *true* value is actually the integer 1. So `p=p` evaluates to the integer 1.

Then that 1 is compared to the 1 in your expression, and this comparison will always be true.

It's not clear what you intended `p=p=1` to test.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!  This was a curiosity I stumbled on.  I also see that this query returns all rows as well.  I'm guessing the p=p explanation doesn't apply in this case?


SELECT * FROM test where p=(p=1)

Comment: Right, if you use parentheses, you can override the default order of operation precedence, like in any other logical or arithmetic expression.
What is that supposed to do? It compares `p` to a boolean expression, which can only be 1 or 0.

Comment: *which is trivially true* ... until p is NULL.

Comment: Good point. I have added that to the paragraph in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

mysql goes from Left to write

```
p=p
```

is always true

```
 true  = 1
```

And mysql sets true as number 1 and false as 0

So the expression is always true

As Akina pointed out if `p is NULL`

the compassion will return false as seen in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9by6GKNcQfNE2NTvLywtxR/3

Comment: *is always true* ... until p is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
p = p = 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
(p = p) = 1
```

and since there are no nulls, the expression:

```
p = p
```

is always `true` which for MySql is equal to `1`.
So the whole expression is equivalent to:

```
1 = 1
```

which is always `true`.